# Stop Iteration error and records

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Kenneth ritz excellent records library for interfacing with a relational database

```
rec = db.query('select * from dept')
for r in rec:
    print(rec.next)

<bound method RecordCollection.next of <RecordCollection size=1 pending=True>>
<bound method RecordCollection.next of <RecordCollection size=2 pending=True>>
<bound method RecordCollection.next of <RecordCollection size=3 pending=True>>
<bound method RecordCollection.next of <RecordCollection size=4 pending=True>>
C:\Python36\Scripts\ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: generator 'RecordCollection.__iter__' raised StopIteration
```

I am trying to iterate over the results of database query but after the iteration i get a nasty exception any ideas

- a)Why i am hitting this exception ?
- b)Whats the correct way of
  iterating over the resultset ?

I tried this

```
In [63]: for r in rec:
    ...:     print(r)
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:
<Record {"deptno": 10, "dname": "ACCOUNTING", "loc": "NEW YORK"}>
<Record {"deptno": 20, "dname": "RESEARCH", "loc": "DALLAS"}>
<Record {"deptno": 30, "dname": "SALES", "loc": "CHICAGO"}>
<Record {"deptno": 40, "dname": "OPERATIONS", "loc": "BOSTON"}>
C:\Python36\Scripts\ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: generator 'RecordCollection.__iter__' raised StopIteration
```

And i still get that StopIteration warning

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/

Comment: It's not an exception, it's just a non-silent warning.

Comment: Hi Lukasz any way to suppress the warning ? Kind of scary isnt it it tells me something is deprecated

Comment: @user3249433 the library is using a newly deprecated python feature and now you're getting a warning. Hopefully the developer will update it soon. In the meantime check out the [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) module which will allow you to suppress the warning.